# php decrypt string with MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256

Tags: php

```
<?php
function encrypt ($key,$iv,$str)
{     
  $block=mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
  $padding=$block-(strlen($str) % $block);
  $str.=str_repeat(chr($padding), $padding);  
  $encryptxt=mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,$key,$str,MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,$iv);  
  $encryptxt64=base64_encode($encryptxt);
  return $encryptxt64;
}
function decrypt ($key,$iv,$str)
{     
  $block=mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
  $padding=$block-(strlen($str) % $block);
  $str.=str_repeat(chr($padding), $padding);  
  $decryptxt=mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,$key,$str,MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,$iv);  
  $decryptxt64=base64_decode($decryptxt);
  return $decryptxt64;
}
echo encrypt("1234567890123456","12345678901234561234567890123456","test")."\n<br/>";
echo decrypt("1234567890123456","12345678901234561234567890123456","xHqKvRQ6FXehOGGMrKoek04146M2l9bv1ScP6C1qCyg=")."\n<br/>";
?>
```

I found this way can encrypt string,works fine,but when I tried to decrypt a string,above codes does not working.
the decrypt output likes

�   S�'=�ɚ?�

Does anybody know how to fix the decrypt part?Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using `Rijndael-256` - It is not the same as `AES-256`. AES is Rijndael-128 and thus, AES-256 is Rijndael-128 (this refers to the cipher block size) with a 256bit key.

Comment: Yes,I am very sure,does php  support decryption for  MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 mode?

Comment: Just as an FYI, [mcrypt has not been updated since 2007 and may not be secure](http://blog.remirepo.net/post/2015/07/07/About-libmcrypt-and-php-mcrypt)

Comment: I believe you should do base 64 decode before decryption on the string as it is done after encryption( in the first part).  Otherwise, assuming I'm reading it straight, you are decrypting a base64 string and not the original output from encrypt.

Comment: @Machavity Good to know. But then, whats the alternative?

Comment: A good place to start would be http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as I stated in the comments This is what you have

```
  //encrypt
 $encryptxt=mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,$key,$str,MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,$iv);  
  $encryptxt64=base64_encode($encryptxt);

 //decrypt 
   $decryptxt=mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,$key,$str,MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,$iv);  
  $decryptxt64=base64_decode($decryptxt);
```

1. encrypt
2. base64 encode
3. decrypt
4. base64 decode

it should be FILO ( first in last out )

1. encrypt
2. base64 encode
3. base64 decode
4. decrypt

That way you are decrypting the output of encrypt and **not** the base64 encoded output,

Like So:

```
$encryptxt=mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,$key,$str,MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,$iv);  
  $encryptxt64=base64_encode($encryptxt);

//decrypt 
 $decryptxt64=base64_decode($str);
$decryptxt=mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,$key,$decryptxt64,MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,$iv);
```

As a note  MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 is NOT AES 256, for that you need MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 with a 32byte  key, So in some regards 128 is better, ( 128 being a smaller block cypher )

One other thing I would suggest doing is taking a md5 hash of the input string and then preending that to the input string, before encryption.  This is so that when you unecrypt it you can substr the first 32 characters and use that to check the input.  Basically you need to know the input string in order to see if it was decrypted.  But, by hashing it and then comparing like this you no longer need to know that to check that it works.

So all together ( haven't tested it but should get you close )

```
function encrypt ($key,$iv,$str)
{     
  $block=mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
  $padding=$block-(strlen($str) % $block);
  $str.=str_repeat(chr($padding), $padding);  

  ///prepend a md5 hash of the plain text input before encrypting it ( so we can check it later )
  $str = md5( $str ) . $str;

    $encryptxt=mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,$key,$str,MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,$iv);  
  $encryptxt64=base64_encode($encryptxt);
  return $encryptxt64;
}
function decrypt ($key,$iv,$str)
{     
  $block=mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
  $padding=$block-(strlen($str) % $block);
  $str.=str_repeat(chr($padding), $padding);  

  $decryptxt64=base64_decode($str);
  $decryptxt=mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,$key,$decryptxt64,MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,$iv);  

   ///Separate the md5 hash from the other text, and then hash the other text and compare to the hash we included when encrypting  if they are = it all worked.
  /// it is perfectly safe to use md5 here because it will be part of what we encrypt, and not accessible until it is decrypted. 
 ///it's sole purpose is to give us 2 things we can compare to check that the decryption worked
  $hash = substr( $decryptxt, 0, 32); //find first 32 characters (md5 output is always 32 characters long )
  $decryptxt = substr($decryptxt, 33); //find everything after the fist 32
  if( $hash != md5($decryptxt) ){
        die( 'fail' ); /// or some other error
  }


  return $decryptxt64;
}
```

Comment: Thanks too much!Yes,like you said,works like a charm,you save me a lot of time!

Comment: @momo - sure, I added a md5 checksum.  I cant test code at the moment, so sorry if it doesn't work completely.  The idea though is to save a hash inside the encrypted text, so that when you decrypt it you have something you can check ( by hashing the other part of the decrypted output ) that way you dont need to know what was encrypted to check that it was decrypted.  These two parts can be separated easily with substr, because md5 is always 32 long.

Comment: Otherwise ( without a checksum ) we could never tell programmatically that what we put in is what we got out, without knowing the input. Which obviously if you know the input then encrypting it is a moot point, outside of testing.

Comment: Sorry,I am new in stackoverflow,this problem has solved, ArtisiticPhoenix was the best solution,I've accepted the answer,thanks all!